# Should I exclude the assets folder from search engine crawlers in angular

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt, angular

I'm working with angular and had added the `assets` folder as element to exclude from the search engine crawlers, into my `robots.txt` file.

But I now get the following error while testing the site health of my website.
`1 issue with blocked internal resource in robots.txt`

What should I do? Is it a good practice to remove such assets (I have a tons of images into it), or is it better to leave it like it.

Comment: Which tool or software is giving you that error? And what is your reason for wanting to add the assets folder to your robots.txt?

Comment: I'm using the following [semrush](semrush.com) & run their site audit. No Idea on the reason why the assets was added to this file, I had to take over a project & was wondering if it was any standard, but couldn't find nothing on internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually a good idea to allow the entire assets folder to be crawled.

### Images

If you don't allow your images to be crawled, they won't be indexed in image search.  Disallow images from crawling only if you don't want them indexed. If you have multiple sizes of the same image you might want Google to index only the largest size because larger images rank better. You could disallow your small images such as thumbnails.

### CSS, JS, and fonts

You want Googlebot to be able to crawl anything needed to render your pages. If Googlebot can't render your pages correctly, there is a risk that your site will not get fully indexed, indexed incorrectly, or that Google will think that they layout isn't usable.

Answer (score 1):

What type of files are in your assets folder?

If you have images, JS, CSS, etc, it's ok for Googlebot to crawl them. If Googlebot needs JS to render your page, then those files will need to be crawled to render.

You can always block specific folders in your robots.txt if there's something you don't want crawled, but in this case, I would allow crawling.

Comment: assets folder in the Angular framework would normally contains images & fonts